# How could I parse JavaScript Object from .js file in Python?

Tags: javascript, python

I want to get JS object from .js file in Python.
there have my Javascripot file example.

this is .js file.

```
// License: GNU General Public License v3. See license.txt

frappe.query_reports["Employee Birthday"] = {
    "filters": [
        {
            "fieldname":"month",
            "label": __("Month"),
            "fieldtype": "Select",
            "options": "Jan\nFeb\nMar\nApr\nMay\nJun\nJul\nAug\nSep\nOct\nNov\nDec",
            "default": ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", 
                "Dec"][frappe.datetime.str_to_obj(frappe.datetime.get_today()).getMonth()],
        },
        {
            "fieldname":"company",
            "label": __("Company"),
            "fieldtype": "Link",
            "options": "Company",
            "default": frappe.defaults.get_user_default("Company")
        }
    ]
}
```

I need this one in Python .py file
that's my goal that's I wanted.

```py
filters = [
        {
            "fieldname":"month",
            "label": __("Month"),
            "fieldtype": "Select",
            "options": "Jan\nFeb\nMar\nApr\nMay\nJun\nJul\nAug\nSep\nOct\nNov\nDec",
            "default": ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", 
                "Dec"][frappe.datetime.str_to_obj(frappe.datetime.get_today()).getMonth()],
        },
        {
            "fieldname":"company",
            "label": __("Company"),
            "fieldtype": "Link",
            "options": "Company",
            "default": frappe.defaults.get_user_default("Company")
        }
    ]
```

Comment: One way to do so, is to serialize the object in your js file into a JSON string, and deserialize that into an object in your Python script. Does that approach work for you?

Comment: why should js `frappe.defaults.get_user_default("Company")` work in python?

Comment: `frappe.defaults.get_user_default("Company")` this is an js object property